# Как сделать такую область при работе с камерой?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы Camera снимала не весь экран, а лишь некую область.

Я использую классы SurfaceView и Camera.

Если из xml уменшить размер SurfaceView то изображение становиться приплюснутым и сжатым. Можно ли как  - то найти выход из этой ситации.

Я как понимаю надо что - то сделать с самой камерой, а не с SurfaceView.
Вот только как.

На картинке снизу человек сделал так чтобы можно было выделять область. Примерно также я хочу сделать.